# How to start an asychronous gateway from a Spring RestController then pass a message to the next channel?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-integration, integration, gateway

hi I'm using Spring integration and have injected a Gateway into a RestController

```
<int:gateway id="reportsService"
    service-interface="me.service.MyReportingGateway"
    default-request-channel="reportsRequestChannel" />

<int:channel id="reportsRequestChannel" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="reportServiceExecutor" /></int:channel>

<task:executor id="reportServiceExecutor" pool-size="5" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="reportsRequestChannel" output-channel="reportRouterChannel">
    <bean id="reportServiceExecutor" class="me.service.SpecReporting"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="reportRouterChannel" />

<int:router input-channel="reportRouterChannel" method="routeReport" ref="reportRouter"></int:router>

<bean class="me.service.ReportRequestRouter" id="reportRouter">
</bean>

  <int:channel id="report01Channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"></int:queue>
  </int:channel>

  <int:channel id="report02Channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"></int:queue>
  </int:channel>

  <!--  for the channels -->
  <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="1000" id="poller"></int:poller>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="report01Channel"
    output-channel="CallbackChannel" ref="filewriter" method="writeFile">
  </int:service-activator>
  <int:service-activator input-channel="report02Channel"
    output-channel="CallbackChannel" ref="filewriter" method="writeFile">
  </int:service-activator>

  <bean class="me.service.CsvFileWriter" id="filewriter"></bean>

  <int:channel id="CallbackChannel" />

  <int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpOutbound"
    request-channel="CallbackChannel"
    http-method="GET"
    url="http://localhost:8080/services/ping" />
```

My RestController injects the gateway:

```
@Autowired
MyReporting reportsService;
```

and calls the method inside the controller method

```
HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
ReportingResponse arr = new ReportingResponse();
AppError ae = new AppError();
ae.setCode("ANP-SM-1000");
ae.setDescription("Everything Criss!!");
arr.setErrors(ae);

logger.debug("Invoking: reportsService.createReport...");
// Async - this will start the report generation process
reportsService.createReport(reportId,rInput);

return new ResponseEntity<ReportingResponse>(arr, httpStatus);
```

**Since I configured a executor-executor channel with a void return how do I continue within this thread to the next channel which is reportRouterChannel?**

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot provides a nice handle to do it. Adding `@Async` annotation will execute your method asynchronously.

just wrap your method in `async`

```
HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
ReportingResponse arr = new ReportingResponse();
AppError ae = new AppError();
ae.setCode("ANP-SM-1000");
ae.setDescription("Everything Criss!!");
arr.setErrors(ae);

logger.debug("Invoking: reportsService.createReport...");
asyncMethod(reportId,rInput);

return new ResponseEntity<ReportingResponse>(arr, httpStatus);

@Async
public void asyncMethod(String reportId, File rInput){
reportsService.createReport(reportId,rInput);

}
```

Don't forget to add `@EnableAsync` to one of the `@Configuration` classes.
spring will do all the magic for you.